# Python unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, calculator

Im trying to create a program to calculate the monthly payment of a loan. Here is my code

```
#This program will ask for amount of borrow, amount of interest
#, and the number of months of the loan to calculate the payment

print('We are going to caluclate the monthly payment of a loan...\n')
borrowed = input('What is the amount borrow on the loan?')
borrowed = float(borrowed)
interest = input('What is the interest rate on the loan? Enter the percentage: ')
interest = float(interest)
months = input('How long is the loan? Enter in # of months: ')

#calulate the monthly payment
payment = (borrowed*(interest/12)*(1+interest/12)**months)/(((1+interest/12)**months)-1)
payment = format(payment, '.2f')

#print the results
print('\n')
print('The amount of loan is: $', str(borrowed))
print('The interest rate is: ', str(interest) + '%')
print('The length of the loan is: ', str(months) + ' months')
print('The month payment is: $', str(payment))
print('\n')
```

I keep getting TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'float' and 'str' on line 12. I'm not sure how to fix this. Any help would be great!

Comment: Convert `months` to `int`.

Comment: For one thing that line is incredibly difficult to read and comprehend. If there were a mistake there it wont be simple to spot. It might serve you better to break down the calculation into several steps, over several lines. It will be easier to read and it will be more obvious what the source of your errors are.

Comment: Do the same as you had done when taking the previous lines of converting user inputs of strings to `float()`, but instead convert `months` to `int`, `months = int(months)`

Answer (score 0):

Months should be an integer.

```
#This program will ask for amount of borrow, amount of interest
#, and the number of months of the loan to calculate the payment

print('We are going to caluclate the monthly payment of a loan...\n')
borrowed = input('What is the amount borrow on the loan?')
borrowed = float(borrowed)
interest = input('What is the interest rate on the loan? Enter the percentage: ')
interest = float(interest)
months = input('How long is the loan? Enter in # of months: ')
months = int(months)

#calulate the monthly payment
payment = (borrowed*(interest/12)*(1+interest/12)**months)/(((1+interest/12)**months)-1)
payment = format(payment, '.2f')

#print the results
print('\n')
print('The amount of loan is: $', str(borrowed))
print('The interest rate is: ', str(interest) + '%')
print('The length of the loan is: ', str(months) + ' months')
print('The month payment is: $', str(payment))
print('\n')
```

Comment: It could be a float if you prefer. It just can't be a string which is what it is in the posted code.

Answer (score 0):

Your `months` variable is a string. As one of the comments said, convert to int/number

Comment: It can be a float if you want, really depends on what op needs. I would recommend not using a float unless really needed. Slower than int in most cases.

Comment: Well, also any math calculations using floats is slower than with ints. Op probably doesn't need any heavy math logic given the code in the post, but in general its better practice.